# Mark rows on YouTrack from issue.State

Tags: youtrack

I want to mark (maybe with color) issue rows, that have "to be discussed" state in my YouTrack, so that they stand out. Is that possible?

[image]

Comment: If you add an answer, I will accept

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In YouTrack it's possible to assign colors to enum custom field values:

[image]

A state field is essentially an enumeration, so you should be able to mark "to be discussed" with any distinguishable color.